# XML::LibXML matching with multiple namespaces

Tags: excel, perl, xml-parsing

I have an example.xml file containing the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
<Worksheet ss:Name="Master Sheet">
</Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

And I have the following Perl code to parse that file:

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use XML::LibXML;
my $filename = 'example.xml';
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $filename);
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new($dom);
$xpc->registerNs('ss', 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet');
my $match1 = $xpc->findnodes('//Worksheet/ss:Name');
print "XPath $match1\n";
```

I have tried many variations of the argument to extract the string "Master Sheet", but to no avail. Can someone please advise?

Comment: If you actually did need to match multiple namespaces, you'd register two different prefixes with `registerNs`. Remember, the prefix registered with `registerNs` and used in the XPath has no relation to the prefix used in the XML (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default name space and `ss` are identical, so this will work

```
$xpc->findnodes('/ss:Worksheet/@ss:Name')
```

Comment: Thank you. How would it differ if the Namespaces were not identical?

Comment: @geofrey: Then you'd have to register a second prefix for the new namespace. The only difference is that a namespace prefix may not be blank in XPath.